# Some murky usage of the verb "offer"?

Tags: verbs

Can you explain to me why:

> 1 He offered me a book to read. - correct grammar
>
> 2 He offered me a spanner to fix the pipe. - correct grammar
>
> 3 He offered me a book to buy. - wrong grammar (the meaning intended
> is - He suggested that I buy a book.)

They have the same structure. What's the matter?

Answer (score 1):

The object of the verb "offer" must be the thing offered. In the third sentence you are offered the "opportunity to buy a book". That's the meaning you want to capture in "a book to buy". It doesn't work because you are not actually being offered a book.

Answer (score 1):

It's a wrong use of the verb *to offer*.

1. He gave/lent me a book.
2. He handed me a spanner.

In (3), in your intended meaning, the speaker is offering the suggestion that you buy a book, not the book itself.